# add multiple sites to laravel homestead, but first site appears for both domains

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have homestead set up and I had my first project working fine, but when I added my second project the url just mimics the first project.

Below is my mapping:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/username/project1
      to: /home/vagrant/project1folder

    - map: ~/username/project2
      to: /home/vagrant/project2folder/

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/project1folder/public

    - map: orb.app
      to: /home/vagrant/project2folder/public
```

and my hosts file

```
  192.168.10.10   pj1.app www.pj1.app
  192.168.10.10   pj2.app www.pj2.app
```

Comment: Did you run `vagrant reload --provision` after you added the second app? Caution: this command will wipe the database(s) you use.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few reasons this could happen.

Firstly, I see your host file points to the wrong URL's.
Do this in your hosts file

```
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
192.168.10.10   orb.app
```

You haven't defined `pj1.app` or `pj2.app` anywhere in your `homestead.yaml` file.

Secondly - if your hosts file actually is correct and you put the wrong thing in your question - `homestead.yaml` file is very picky when it comes to whitespaces. I've noticed plenty of times it won't work after adding a new site, because my editor was for some reason messing with the whitespaces so vagrant failed.

Try this:

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/project1folder/public
    - map: orb.app
      to: /home/vagrant/project2folder/public
```

Notice no break betweent he two lines.

Of course, do `vagrant provision` after making changes to make sure homestead serves the new sites (from your homestead folder)

Also, you don't have to define a `folder` for every project.

My personal `homestead.yaml` file has this:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: site1.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/site3/public
    - map: site2.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/site2/public
    - map: site3.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/site3/public
```

This would, on my windows machine, map the Projects folder to `C:\Users\MyUsername\Projects` as `~` basically means your user folder

As you can see, I define one Projects `folder` and multiple `sites` go under those folders. It will make everything much simpler for you, especially when adding new projects.

Comment: I have all this set up correctly but homestead shows site1.dev when I navigate to site2.dev. Also, it is not creating my databases, I have to create them manually via `mysql` in the machine. AAAND ... if I do reload, it fails to mount the folder. I have to turn the vm off and start it again .. Somethings definitely fishy with vagrant & homestead recently